# Gulp concat using stale file information

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

Disclaimer: I'm new to gulp

This seems to be obvious, but I can't get gulp concat to correctly concatenate the output from another gulp task.  Here is a gulp file that demonstrates the problem I'm having.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('task1', function() {
    gulp.src(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'task2-output.txt', 'file3.txt'])
        .pipe(concat('output.txt'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});

gulp.task('task2', function() {
    gulp.src('task2-input.txt')
        .pipe(concat('task2-output.txt'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['task2', 'task1']);
```

"task1" is supposed to be including file1.txt, file2.txt, task2-output.txt, and file3.txt in that order.  The problem is, task2-output.txt is not getting included properly.  It appears that task1 is including the contents of task2-output.txt as it appears when the gulp command is run.  If task2-output.txt is missing when gulp starts, it's left out.  If task2-input.txt is modified, task2-output.txt is modified by task2 but the old version is included in output.txt

If I specifically run gulp task2 and gulp task1 separately in that order, it works fine.  It's when I run the default task that it fails.

Here is a sample session:

```
C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>type file1.txt
File 1
C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>type file2.txt
File 2
C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>type task2-input.txt
Task 2
C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>type file3.txt
File 3
C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>gulp
[10:35:15] Using gulpfile ~\htdocs\gulptest\gulpfile.js
[10:35:15] Starting 'task2'...
[10:35:15] Finished 'task2' after 7.76 ms
[10:35:15] Starting 'task1'...
[10:35:15] Finished 'task1' after 3.67 ms
[10:35:15] Starting 'default'...
[10:35:15] Finished 'default' after 15 μs

C:\Users\Ken\htdocs\gulptest>type output.txt
File 1
File 2
File 3
```

Comment: Try adding a return statement to your tasks ala:  return gulp.src.....

Comment: Adding the return statements almost fixed it.  I also had to add task2 as a dependency of task1.  I'll post an answer.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Glad that helped.  Now I wouldn't think you need the task2 call in your default task.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's comment led me to the working solution.  I had to add return statements to each task and add task2 as a dependency of task1.  Adding the return statements alone didn't fix it.  Neither did adding the task dependency alone.  Both changes were necessary.  Here is the working solution.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('task1', ['task2'], function() {
    return gulp.src(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'task2-output.txt', 'file3.txt'])
        .pipe(concat('output.txt'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});

gulp.task('task2', function() {
    return gulp.src('task2-input.txt')
        .pipe(concat('task2-output.txt'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['task2', 'task1']);
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, despite already using runSequence to theoretically do exactly what I wanted.